# Run a python script, but point to another installation of python

Tags: python, linux, command-line

I have a python script that I am attempting to run on linux, called main.py.

Command line

```
python main.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
from parser_functions import get_values, validation,vhd_file,pdl_file
File "/vobs/embedded/tools/parser_python/parser_functions.py", line 3, in   <module>
from docx import Document
ImportError: No module named docx
```

I think that it can't my current libraries, I have my libraires intalled but in a different location. How can I link the command with the libraries in a custom location?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to install your custom libraries with [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) ?

If you want yo use an other python installation just execute your scripts with the other python binaries

Also you should considere using [virtual environement](https://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)